# AWS EC2 - what is the difference between Amazon Linux AMIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When launching a new EC2 instance, I can select between 2 different Amazon Linux images:

1. Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type
2. Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type

What is the difference?

[image]

Comment: AWS has extensive documentaion on this. https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option is your image is a more stripped down/bare bones Linux image while the second includes commonly used packages/tools that are used when creating hosted services (such as AWS command line tools and Ruby).

I have an Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type and you can see that extra packages like java and ruby are not installed.

[image]

Comment: This is not the whole answer though. The documentation describes the details: https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/ "How is Amazon Linux 2 different from Amazon Linux AMI?"

Answer (score 1):

The primary differences between Amazon Linux 2 and Amazon Linux AMI are:

1. Amazon Linux 2 offers long-term support until June 30, 2023.
2. Amazon Linux 2 is available as virtual machine images for on-premises
   development and testing.
3. Amazon Linux 2 provides the systemd service and systems manager as opposed to System V init system in Amazon Linux AMI.
4. Amazon Linux 2 comes with an updated Linux kernel, C library, compiler, and tools.
5. Amazon Linux 2 provides the ability to
   install additional software packages through the extras mechanism.

For more [click here](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/#:%7E:text=The%20primary%20differences%20between%20Amazon%20Linux%202%20and%20Amazon%20Linux%20AMI%20are%3A&text=Amazon%20Linux%202%20is%20available%20as%20virtual%20machine%20images%20for,system%20in%20Amazon%20Linux%20AMI.)